# java - File reader/writer crashing and not working

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am making a program for someone that read/writes to a file. I created it, and tested it, but it crashes when I tell it the name.
Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    print("Enter a name for the bell: ");
    String bellname = scanner.nextLine();

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("normbells.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fs);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("normbells.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fr);
    String line;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int index = line.indexOf(":");

        if(index == -1) {}else{
            String name = line.substring(0, index);

            if(bellname.equals(name)) {
                print("This bell name is already taken!");
                line = null;
                return;
            }

            print("Enter a time for the bell (24-hour format, please): ");

            String time = scanner.nextLine();

            String toWrite = name + ":" + time;

            boolean hasFoundNull = false;
            String currentString;

            while(hasFoundNull == false) {
                currentString = br.readLine();

                if(currentString == null) {
                    hasFoundNull = true;
                    bw.write(toWrite);
                }else{}
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void print(String args) {
    System.out.println(args);
}
}
```

Here is the output:
    Enter a name for the bell: 
    Durp

Here is the file content:
Actually, the file is empty. It wiped it for some reason. Here is what it originally had:
    Durp:21:00

Comment: Don't try reading & writing to a file at the same time.  Open it, read it, close it. Open it, write it, close it.

Comment: Nope. Just <terminated> as it says in Eclipse.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, i'll try that. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Patrick Forgot that, i'll try that. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: Was there some part of the last two words of *"Open it, write it, **close it.**"*  that you are having trouble understanding? O_o

Comment: @cheese5505: Would you mind updating your question with your new code?

Comment: Don't mix DataInputStream and BufferedReader, you don't need DataInputStream here, I would remove it.

Comment: @Patrick `BufferedWriter.close()` 'closes the stream, flushing it first'. You do need to stop spreading this misinformation.

Comment: @EJP: I'm just trying to help, you don't have to be rude

Comment: @Patrick Your comment contained misinformation you have perpetrated on other occasions. Saying so isn't 'rude', it is a necessary and standard part of any critical exchange.

Comment: @EJP: I never stated that close does not call flush first. I suggested that OP might try to flush the content before the application exits.

Comment: @EJP: On other occasions? You mean that *one* question about socket.isConnected? I'm sorry I got that wrong..

Comment: @Patrick As your comment has now been mysteriously deleted, it is impossible to verify that claim: however, that is not my recollection of what it contained. The fact that it didn't solve the OP's problem is also relevant. Not sure how many times you need to be corrected but I will persist in correcting misinformation wherever I see it.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, I removed both comments, as they were wrong and contained misinformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileWriter` also has the constructor `FileWriter(String, boolean)`, where the boolean flag means "append".
If you do not specify it, it will be false and the file cleared before writing to it.

So, replace

```
fr = new FileWriter("normbells.txt");
```

with

```
fr = new FileWriter("normbells.txt", true);
```

and maybe it will work.